Azure Pipeline MS-hosted mac agent: CopyFiles Task takes a very long time
I've recently migrated some of my build steps to Microsoft-Hosted mac agents.
After creating .dmg of my app (about 10MB), I copy it into the Artifacts Staging di3rectory. This used to take seconds on my self-hosted mac agents, but now consistently takes about 15 minutes!
This should be a local file copy operation and should be much quicker. Has anyone experienced something similar?
Here's my YAML in case
- job: MacOSApp
  pool:
      name: 'Azure Pipelines' # Use Microsoft Agent 
      vmImage: 'macOS-14'
  steps:
  - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy App'
      inputs:
          SourceFolder: 'deploy/build-app/output'
          Contents: 'MyApp.dmg'
          TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          CleanTargetFolder: false
          OverWrite: true
          flattenFolders: true
          preserveTimestamp: true

Agent version 3.241.0, image version: 20240707.1
I've tried without success:

running on macos-13 or macos-12
turning off flattenFolders and preserveTimestamp options

UPDATE: I've tried adding a ArchiveFiles@2 step to create a .zip and then copying thart. In this case, the ArchiveFiles@2 step times out after 50 minutes (!)

Not sure if it might be related, but there have been some issues in Azure DevOps in the last few days.

The problem seems to have been due to the contents of my .dmg, which contains MyApp.app and a symbolic link to /Applications (so users can drag App to install). If I remove the link, the copy operation behaves normally.
I found a workaround: Use a Finder 'alias' instead of symbolic link.
I'm running the following in a bash step to create an alias in the current working directory:
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' \
   -e "make alias file to (POSIX file \"/Applications\") \ 
      at (POSIX file \"$PWD\") with properties {name:\"Applications\"}" \
   -e 'end tell'

(For reference: I used to create the symlink like this: ln -s /Applications Applications)

I tested this in my organization (Geography is Europe), and macOS-14 took only 2 seconds to copy files of about 12MB using the CopyFiles@2 task.
You can try other image, macOS-13 or macOS-12, and check if it takes a long time.

I tried this, but it doesn't improve:
macOS-13 : operation takes >20 mins,  macOS-12: 15mins
I'm in northern Switzerland.
Agent version 3.241.0, image version: 20240707.1

I've also tried adding a ArchiveFiles@2 step to create a .zip and then copying thart. In this case, the ArchiveFiles@2 step times out after 50 minutes (!)

To narrow down the issue, you can try these suggestions: 1. Copy other files of about 10 MB and check whether the pipeline takes a long time. 2. Add variable system.debug and set the value to true, then trigger the pipeline. Check the log to understand what operations the pipeline is performing and which operations take a long time. 3. Create a new organization in other regions (If you don't have one), copy the same .dmg in the pipeline and check what's the result.

UPDATE: I think I found the source of the issue.
The folder dmgcontent that I use to createmy .dmg (hdiutil) contains my MyApp.app plus a symbolic link ln -s /Applications dmgcontent/Applications. If I remove the symbolic link, the .dmg copies in seconds, as it should.
Any idea why a symbolic link would make the CopyFiles@2 task go crazy?
I've been doing this for years on my self-hosted mac agents.

Not sure about it. I am guessing the CopyFiles@2 task might be trying to follow the symbolic link and copy the contents it points to. When you use a self-hosted agent, maybe these contents were already installed before. Or it may take time for the new agent to resolve the symbolic link. You can set up a new self-hosted on a new machine and check if there is the same problem or not.

I'm not installing anything -- all the symbolic link does is appear as an alias of the /Applications folder when the user opens the dmg. Then, they can drag the .app onto "Applications" to install, as it is usual on macos. So the state of the agent does not play a role.

I just found a workaround:  I'm generating an "alias" with Finder instead of using a symbolic link -- when doing this, everything works as expected: the copying takes a couple of seconds and the shorctcut appears in the .dmg. I will post that as an answer - thank you very much for your help nevertheless!
